# Llave duplicada al insertar con hibernate en clases heredadas

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate, jpa

Hola espero me puedan ayudar, tengo un problema con las inserciones en hibernate.
Primero tengo una clase Persona

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "persons")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
public class Person implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id_card", columnDefinition = "VARCHAR(13)")
    private String idCard;

    @Column(name = "name", columnDefinition = "VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL")
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "last_name", columnDefinition = "VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL")
    private String lastName;
}
```

Y tengo dos clases mas la una proveedor

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "providers")
public class Provider extends Person implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public Provider() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }
}
```

Cliente

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "customers")
public class Customer extends Person implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public Customer() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }
}
```

Lo que sucede es que inserto un proveedor y no hay nigún problema, al igual que al insertar cliente no hay problema, lo que ocurre es que cuando ya inserte a una persona como cliente ya no la puedo insertar como proveedor me sale que ya existe la llave.

Lo que sucede es que una persona puede ser cliente y proveedor o empleado a la vez.

Modelo entidad-relación
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Puedes subir tu modelo de tablas de base de datos?

Comment: Claro ya edito la pregunta

Answer (score 1):

En este caso no tiene sentido la herencia, estás trabajando con clave foráneas.
Puedes probar algo así:

@Entity
@Table(name = "customers")
public class Customer  implements Serializable {

```
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
```

@OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@MapsId
@JoinColumn(name="id")
private Person person;

```
public Customer() {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}
```

}

Lo mismo para Employee y Provider.

Comment: Lo que pasa es que proveedor, tiene direccion de sucursal y un cliente tiene puntos ganados, y a su vez el empleado tiene atributos como el dia que entro a trabajar y el dia de termino.

Comment: La cosa es que no tiene sentido la herencia, ya que las tablas customer, provider y employee no tienen ningún campo de person, sino el id como FK.

Comment: Gracias, tienes razón